UEFI Application prints only last character of read file
I wrote a UEFI Application in EDK2 to read a file "HelloWorld.txt" in the root directory to the buffer and print it.It only prints the last character from the text file. What did I do wrong? It should read the whole text. I added error checking for each step and everything runs fine, so I assume it's  small error and my general approach is correct?
#include <Uefi.h>
#include <Library/UefiApplicationEntryPoint.h>
#include <Library/UefiLib.h>
#include <Library/UefiBootServicesTableLib.h>
#include <Protocol/SimpleFileSystem.h>

#define BufferSize 1024

EFI_STATUS EFIAPI UefiMain(IN EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, IN EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE* SystemTable) {
    EFI_STATUS Status = EFI_SUCCESS;
    EFI_SIMPLE_FILE_SYSTEM_PROTOCOL* SimpleFileSystem;
    EFI_FILE_PROTOCOL* RootDir;
    EFI_FILE_PROTOCOL* File = NULL;
    CHAR16 FilePath[] = L"\\HelloWorld.txt";
    UINTN FileSize;
    UINT8 Buffer[BufferSize];

    // Locate the simple file system protocol
    Status = gBS->LocateProtocol(&gEfiSimpleFileSystemProtocolGuid, NULL, (VOID **)&SimpleFileSystem);

    if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
        Print(L"Failed to locate simple file system protocol.\n");

        return Status;
    }

    // Open the root directory of the file system
    Status = SimpleFileSystem->OpenVolume(SimpleFileSystem, &RootDir);

    if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
        Print(L"Failed to open root directory of file system.\n");

        return Status;
    }

    // Open the file in read mode
    Status = RootDir->Open(RootDir, &File, FilePath, EFI_FILE_MODE_READ, 0);

    if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
        Print(L"Failed to open %c in read mode.\n", FilePath);
        RootDir->Close(RootDir);

        return Status;
    }

    // Get file size
    Status = File->SetPosition(File, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF);

    if (!EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
        Status = File->GetPosition(File, &FileSize);
    }

    if(EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
        Print(L"Failed to get file size of %c.\n", FilePath);
        File->Close(File);
        RootDir->Close(RootDir);

        return Status;
    }

    // Read the file content into buffer
    Status = File->SetPosition(File, 0);

    if (!EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
        Status = File->Read(File, &FileSize, Buffer);
    }

    if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
        Print(L"Failed to read file content.\n");
        File->Close(File);
        RootDir->Close(RootDir);

        return Status;
    }
    else {
        Buffer[FileSize] = '\0';
    }

    // Close file and root directory
    File->Close(File);
    RootDir->Close(RootDir);

    // Print file content
    Print(L"File content: %s\n", Buffer);

    return Status;
}


At the line Buffer[FileSize] = '\0';, you need to check what is the value of FileSize, and what is recorded in Buffer.  Use the debugger to help you.

Checked it, file size is 13, that's the correct length of "Hello, World!". I don't know, it should work.

Well as I said you need to look inside the buffer to see what has been read from the file. My only (vague) guess is that the file contains Unicode text and you are trying to print ASCII.

If the file contains 13 bytes it doesn't contain unicode, if it contains ascii code you need to print it with %a instead of %s.
